# webBrowser control not displaying PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have problem in displaying pdf image in the webBrowser control. The file name is search in the web browser.

refer to image below:
[image]

Code:

```cs
FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //textBox5.Text = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath).Parent.Parent.Name;
                
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.pdf");
    // string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(FBD.SelectedPath);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(new FileInfo(file).Name);
    }
```

```cs
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    string filedirectory = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null && listBox1.SelectedItem is string)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(filedirectory);
    
                            //   if (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
```

Comment: In the ListBox you add only the Name of the file. Then you ask the browser to display that file but you fail to give the full path to the file, so it seems the control going to search for it using Bing.

Comment: Thanks. this code solve the isuse                 listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(file)); but in listbox1 display full path name. i want to display filename only

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```cs
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath, "*.pdf");

foreach (string file in files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(new FileInfo(file).Name);
}
```

do this:

```cs
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath);
var files = folder.GetFiles("*.pdf");

listBox1.DisplayMember = nameOf(FileInfo.Name);
listBox1.ValueMember = nameOf(FileInfo.FullName);
listBox1.DataSource = files;
```

and then, instead of this:

```cs
string filedirectory = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

do this:

```cs
var filePath = (string)listBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Note the use of a variable name that actually describes what the variable represents. "filedirectory" is a nonsense.

Comment: On the right track, but I don't think it will work if you use an array of strings as the DataSource of the Listbox

Comment: @Steve, you're right. I was thinking that `files` was a `FileInfo` array but I see that that impression came from elsewhere in the code. Have fixed.